# Yii-2, Замена пути к контроллерам в зависимости от стартовой странницы

Tags: yii2, mvc, controller, route

По умолчанию, все роуты с yii-2 начинаются из файла index.php и задаються параметром "r={controller}/{action}".

Можно ли подменить адресацию, ели начальной страницей будет, к примеру: admin.php.

Задача какая: должно быть два отдельных дизайна и разная политика безопасносности для админки и основной части сайта, некоторые action-ны совпадают (список номеров отеля: 1 - grid с возможностью редактирования, 2 - страница с возможностью бронировать номера).

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро.

Какой именно шаблон yii2 Вы используете? Basic или advanced?

В advanced уже есть разделение на admin и пользовательскую части.
Если basic, то создаются отдельные модули, например модуль admin. При помощи rbac делается разграничение прав доступа.

> Можно ли подменить адресацию, ели начальной страницей будет, к примеру: admin.php.

Зачем? Чего именно Вы хотите добиться? Заменить имя входного скрипта? Тогда опять же, зачем?

Создать разный дизайн для разных частей сайта особого труда не составит.

> некоторые action-ны совпадают

В смысле? Покажите пример Ваших действий.

В общем из Вашего вопроса мало что можно понять. Уточните и дополните вопрос.

Comment: основную проблему решено, спасибо, разделение на admin и front часть это то что нужно.
Как лучше сменить шаблон yii2 на advanced?

Comment: Где именно, на что именно? Подключить дизайн?